# what is syntax to make a second expand on a oData call in sapui5?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I now have tableitems that are retrieved like this:

```
<Table
    id="table"
    width="auto"
    class="sapUiResponsiveMargin"
    items="{
        path: '/InvoiceSet',
        sorter: {
            path: 'InvNr',
            descending: false
        },
        parameters: {
            expand: 'NavInvoiceItem'
        }
    }"
```

but i want to add the expantion NavInvoiceAttachment
i have tried this:

```
expand: 'NavInvoiceItem',
        'NavInvoiceAttachments'
```

and this

```
expand: ['NavInvoiceItem',
         'NavInvoiceAttachments']
```

and this

```
expand: {'NavInvoiceItem',
         'NavInvoiceAttachments'}
```

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: tried the "in a single string, seperated by comma"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marvin Smit commented is the solution a single string seperated by a comma like this:

```
expand: 'NavInvoiceItem,NavInvoiceAttachments'
```